# Generating a series with mean=0 and variance=1

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, variance

Assume that we want to generate a set of numbers (integer values) having mean=0 and variance=1. Size of this set is even and elements are symmetric which means that half of them are negative values and the other half are positive with the same values (e.g {-2,-1,1,2}). Base on the symmetrical property, the mean of this set is always zero. How can we choose the values such that the variance of this set equals to 1, only by knowing the size of the set? Is there a mathematical way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Let us break this down
$$
\mathbb{E}(X) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^Nx_k
$$
So the mean is (relatively) easy as we just require
$$
\sum_{k=0}^Nx_k = 0
$$
Then the variance is 
$$
\mathbb{V}(X) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^N\left(x_k-\mathbb{E}(X)\right)^2
$$
or
$$
\mathbb{V}(X) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^N x_k^2 -\mathbb{E}^2(X) 
$$
Then if all things being considered is
$$
\mathbb{V}(X) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^N x_k^2 - 0
$$
so the two constraints are
$$
\sum_{k=0}^N x_k = 0\\
\sum_{k=0}^N x_k^2 = N
$$
This may or may not be easy.

Comment: Supplied missing lower limits 0 to summations.

Comment: Easy to meet constraints if $N$ is even and there are $N/2$ observations $-1$ and $N/2$ observations $1.$ Also sum of first $k$ squares is $k(k+1)(2k+1)/6$ So if $N = k(k+1)(2k+1)/3$ we can have $-k, -(k-1), \dots 0, 1, \dots, k.$

Comment: @bruceet great point. I have to think about what you said,  but if you could put that as an answer it  will be awesome to have.

Comment: Thanks, the comment already says what I know. No use competing with your nice answer.

Comment: So in effect if you want $2N$ symmetric integer values with mean $0$ and variance $1$, you partition $N$ into squares (the number of ways of doing this is in [OEIS A001156](https://oeis.org/A001156)); then take the values as the positive and negative square roots and fill any remaining values with $0$.  So for example with $8$ values, you have $\frac{8}{2}=1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2 =2^2$ so the two possible multisets are $\{1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1\}$ and $\{2,-2,0,0,0,0,0,0\}$

Comment: @Henry I did not consider the solutions of the constraint problem - but yes those subsets satisfy the condition. I would consider you to add that as a follow on to this or in addition to another approach that you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: I am happy with your answer, like @BruceET. My comment was for my own benefit

Comment: @Henry thanks for the addition - sorry I took so long to get back. Don't really contribute too much these days.